# How to import archive in xcode 5

Tags: xcode, archive

I am pretty new to the archive functions in Xcode 5.

I am trying to migrate a project from one machine to another. Normally, I can do this by transferring the entire file structure of that project. But, I was trying to do this using an archive. I have no problems archiving, and have no problems migrating that actual archive to the new machine. But, for the life of me, I cannot see how to open that Archive as a project and keep working. Is my concept way off? If so, what is the purpose of archiving anyway?
Cheers, Craig

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I understand this question correctly, If it is about opening .xcarchive file.
Here is the way.

Create a directory (say, 2014-01-21) in following path

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives

put the .xcarchive file in the directory
the archive will show up in Organizer.